# Can not login to phpmyadmin

Tags: 16.04, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

My phpmyadmin was working fine, But suddenly I get the error while I try to login in phpmyadmin [image]

Than I test mysql on CLI by typing **sudo service mysql start** and got error **Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.**

the log file /etc/var/log/mysql/error.log showing this

```
2017-06-22T07:33:14.316527Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2017-06-22T07:33:14.316562Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2017-06-22T07:33:14.316577Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2017-06-22T07:33:14.917014Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2017-06-22T07:33:14.917060Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-06-22T07:33:14.917073Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2017-06-22T07:33:14.917082Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2017-06-22T07:33:14.917093Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2017-06-22T07:33:14.917747Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

What to do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the permissions on the `mysql` data directory is owned by the `mysql` user.

```
sudo ls -al /var/lib/mysql
```

Everything in that list should be owned by `mysql` (except the `..` entry which would be owned by `root`).

If it's not the case, run the following command to fix it:

```
sudo chown -R mysql: /var/lib/mysql
```